# Rails 4 Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound / Couldn't find 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, controller

I'm fairly new to rails and into coding my first app. Just can't figure out how to target the following stuff in my controller.

Controller

```
def index
  @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
  @favorites = current_user.favorites
  @tools = Tool.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  @user = current_user
end
```

Index View

```
%h2 My Favorite Tools
- @favorites.each do |tool|
    = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= @tool.impressionist_count
    %p= link_to @tool.get_upvotes.size, like_tool_path(@tool), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
    %p
        http://ocubit.com/tools/
        = @tool.id
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)

%h2 My Tools
- @tools.each do |tool|
    = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= @tool.impressionist_count
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
    %p
        http://ocubit.com/tools/
        = @tool.id
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)


= link_to "View Your Profile", '/users/'+@user.id.to_s

-if @user.use_gravatar?
    = image_tag gravatar_for @user
- else
    = image_tag @user.avatar_filename.url

%h1= @user.username

= link_to "Edit", edit_user_registration_path
```

If I run this in my browser it appears following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ToolsController#index
Couldn't find Tool with 'id'=
```

I've already changed my controller to (to test)

```
@tool = Tool.find(1)
```

And that works, so the issue has to be there. I simply can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It is a bit unusual to pass an `id` parameter to an `index` action. Typically routes for `index` actions don't take an `id` parameter for the collection you're viewing. I think you probably want to remove the `@tool = Tool.find(params[:id])` line altogether, and then change all of the `@tool`'s in your view to `tool`.

Comment: Check your rake routes. Also check params section on error page to make sure :id param is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need this line:

@tool = Tool.find(params[:id])

If you are in the index views, you want to show all the tools, not just one. THat would be for the :show view. You don't have a params[:id] in the index view, you are not specifing that in the url.

So:

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @favorites = @user.favorites
  @tools = @user.tools.order("created_at DESC")
end



%h2 My Favorite Tools
- @favorites.each do |tool|
    = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= tool.impressionist_count
    %p= link_to tool.get_upvotes.size, like_tool_path(tool), method: :get
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
    %p
        http://ocubit.com/tools/
        = tool.id
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)

%h2 My Tools
- @tools.each do |tool|
    = image_tag tool.cover_filename.url
    %h2= link_to tool.title, tool
    %p= tool.subtitle
    %p= tool.impressionist_count
    %p= link_to "Edit", edit_tool_path(tool)
    %p
        http://ocubit.com/tools/
        = tool.id
    %p= time_ago_in_words(tool.created_at)


= link_to "View Your Profile", '/users/'+@user.id.to_s

-if @user.use_gravatar?
    = image_tag gravatar_for @user
- else
    = image_tag @user.avatar_filename.url

%h1= @user.username

= link_to "Edit", edit_user_registration_path
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to `params[:id]` equals to `nil`. Try to open this URL then change the code to:

```
# open this URL to pass parameter tool_id
http://localhost:3000/favorites?tool_id=1

# in view 
<%= link_to "Favorites", favorites_path(tool_id: 1) %>

# controller
def index
  @tool = Tool.find(params[:tool_id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

They key is you have no params[:id] in your index controller. Remove this line: 
    @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])

Instead of @tool use just 'tool' in your view

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is alot of correct of correct answers already before this one, but i would like to do a bit more then giving you the solution.

in fact what
 `@tool = Tool.find(params[:id])`
does is, it will take from your URL, the ID..

let's say you have on your broswer

```
http://localhost:3000/tool/1
```

This you get you ID param as the number one.

The great BUT here is, you are on your index.. and everytime you go to you Index "website" ( index view to be exact), on your URL you will see something like

```
ttp://localhost:3000/tools
```

that is why you are getting this error " the URL has no ID on it"

But ruby on rails is like any other language, and you need to understand it, and DAMM ruby is mean on that.. and for ruby.. `Tools != Tool`
this little 's' mean you wanna see ALL of your tools so there is no need to send an ID with it, on the other hand you SHOW will show you ONE of your tolls, giving you the URL `http://localhost:3000/tool/1` , or in other words, you will see your tool that have the ID = 1

in fact, what you want on your Controller index is something to show all of your tools so..

@tools = Tool.all

or something with the relations with you current_user and favorite list

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Got it.